# How do I enable source map support in Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug, source-maps

I've been using Chrome for a good while now, and you have to explicitly enable souce map support in the options.

I'm testing something in Firefox now with Firebug, but I'm not seeing my original source files - just the generated bundle.

Is there some way to enable source map support in Firebug? I'm  using Firebug 1.12.8 in Firefox 27.0.1.

Comment: Now that firebug supports source maps, I want to turn it off lol!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Firebug doesn't support source maps yet (as of 2.0.*).

You may want to follow [issue 5765](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5765) for source maps support for JavaScript and [issue 5961](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5961) for CSS.

Firebug 3 will integrate into the built-in DevTools of Firefox, which already have this feature. So Firebug 3 will also have that feature. Development versions are [available at getfirebug.com](http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/3.0/).

**Update**:

Firebug is merged into the Firefox DevTools since [Firefox 48](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/48.0/releasenotes/).

Comment: In opposite to the other devtools Firebug is maintained by a handful of volunteer contributors, so resources are somewhat limited. But it's [open source](https://github.com/firebug/firebug), so you may want to [help the team](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_become_a_contributor) by providing a patch for that.

Comment: In the mean time you can use sourcemaps in Firefox's style editor. New in Firefox 29. https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/css-source-map-support-network-performance-analysis-more-firefox-developer-tools-episode-29/

Comment: The issue for CSS source maps has now been moved to [7419](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7419)