# How to see SCSS in Firefox Firebug?

Tags: sass, firebug

[This FF add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-gb/firefox/addon/firecompass-for-firebug/) allows to see Compass-generated SCSS in Firebug, but I don't work with Compass. Is there not any way at the moment to debug non-compass SCSS in FF Firebug?

Comment: Did you try enabling source-mapping in Firefox.
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/live-editing-sass-and-less-in-the-firefox-developer-tools/

Comment: Not interested in using FF developer tools, I prefer Firebug.

Comment: Note that Firebug [does not work anymore once multi-process Firefox is enabled](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/) (which will happen by default in Firefox 49 [according to the related page on the Mozilla wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Schedule_and_Status)). Instead the Firefox DevTools have a Firebug theme since Firefox 48. If you're missing things Firebug had, you should follow [bug 991806](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=991806).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously there was a Firebug extension called [FireSass](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/) available, though unfortunately it's development is obviously discontinued.

So, at the moment there is only FireCompass adding support for SCSS files. And because the [development on Firebug is discontinued](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/), it is very unlikely that it will receive SCSS support in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To get access to this feature in the browser, you need to generate a source map file for each source file.[sass-source mapping](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass)

Comment: I use WordPress Sage which already generates a source map file, but still I only see the Gulp-generated CSS end-result in Firebug, not my SCSS code.

Comment: @drake035 this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346708/how-do-i-enable-source-map-support-in-firebug